# Find a pattern of character in a column

Tags: string, character, similarity

I have some trouble with matching two columns.

I try to do this in excel first (shame on me), but I think that maybe it will be easier with R.

So I have one list of references, **REF** (actually one column of a data frame) and others list (other columns of my dataframe).
I want to know if I can find the string in REF in my other list L1 (other column). 
BUT in L1, I may have others character in the string.

*For example in REF I have 'ABCDE' and in L1: 'ABCDEFG'.*
How can I do in R to find those similarities?

I hope I was clear enough to explain my problem.

Thanks a lot for your help!

A.

Here some wonderful example of what my data looks like:

```
REF               L1
ABCD             AAAF
EFGH             IIIII
IJKLM            QWERTY
NO               NOMRR
PQRSTUV          SFTTY
                 FTFTFGY
                 ABCDEF
```

Comment: Your examples strings aren't in your data example. What is REF? What is L1? What similarities?

Comment: REF is a column in a data frame with x string. L1 is another column with x string. Similiarities means find a pattern in a string ABCD = ABCDE.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful edit. "In REF I have 'ABCDE'" No, the closest you have in REF to that is 'ABCD'. Do you mean you're looking for near matches for these strings in those columns?

Comment: If I want to be more specific, I am looking for peptides with missed cleavages. So in my REF I have a specific sequence for example 'ABCD' and maybe in my other list L1 I may have 'ABCDE' or maybe 'ABCDEF' whatever. The point is, I have the same begining and maybe some addition in my string.